# Bootstrap 4 - Center Buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

How to center buttons given these requirements?

1. button width is variable.
2. all button width needs to be set to the largest width button (equal widths).
3. buttons must be stacked vertically.

This works but I cannot center them.

```html
 <div class="d-inline-flex flex-column"> 
  <button type="button">Width1</button>
  <button type="button">Width2</button> 
  <button type="button">Width3</button> 
 </div>
```

Comment: check this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_group_vertical.asp

Comment: thanks for suggestion but @w3s example.btn-group works only with defined width (set width: 50%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: create an old school wrapper + btn-group-vertical

```html
<div class="d-block mx-auto text-center">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <button type="button">Width1</button>
    <button type="button">Width2</button> 
    <button type="button">Width3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Credit: https://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/mrNVPG

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your intended layout and break points....

You could use btn-block as the standard button.  Btn-block does of course fill the width available to it and centres the button text.

You could then confine each btn-block by placing them within columns within a row. As they then break and stack they will expand/contract to the new width available to them.

If this is what you mean?  I have used it successfully and to good effect.

[Desktop View1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfglg.png)

[Mobile View1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25l3o.png)

[Desktop View 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8qoY.png)

[Mobile View 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjZkF.png)